# Client-Side Quote Calculator

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm building a quote calculator that makes all the calculations client side with Javascript, and then if the person wishes to go ahead with the quote, all the information they've entered will be copied from the list structure into a form and submitted via PHP.

Is it likely that there will be any issues that will cause the browser to freeze during this process, causing the user to refresh and lose all of the details they've entered?

The reason I'm worried about freezing is because parts of the quote calculator will include JSON requests for Google Maps API v3 services, and I think that increases the chances of getting non responsive webpages.

If there are potential issues, how can I plan to avoid them best?

Is there a way to save the details they enter without an active server connection, in case they have to refresh, I'm thinking probably a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. JSON requests to Google Maps **can** result in freezing screens/unresponsive pages, but this problem unfortunately cannot be minimized because it depends on the client's browser or computer speed, as that is quite a heavyweight request.
2. A cookie is a good idea for temporarily saving data that they've entered, but you will have to set it when they do something on the page, like pressing a submit button. Bear in mind also that the cookie will not become active until the page is refreshed or another page is navigated to.

Comment: I forgot to include the reason I was worried about these issues, thanks for your answer, it helps to reassure. Please see edited question above.

Comment: @DominicB-c that's fine. I'm glad to have helped :)